# Need a query to move all the emails from one table into another using a common row value as the link

Tags: sql, mysql

An import was performed on my database which wasn't done so well. It's resulted in some fields being empty where they shoudln't, etc...

What I need to do now is move all the data from one column in one table into a column in a different table. Both tables have an ID which is a link to each rows.

For example:

```
Table1

id | linkID | email
---+--------+-------------------
1  |  7     | 
---+--------+-------------------
2  |  3     | fake@gmail.com

Table2

id | email
---+-----------------
7  | user@server.com
---+-----------------
3  | fake@gmail.com
```

I was going to write a small PHP script to pull out all the rows from Table2 and UPDATE Table1 using the `id` and `email`. But I was wondering if this could be done entirely through SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set email = (select email from table2 where table1.linkID=table2.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
inner join table2 on table1.linkID = table2.id
set table1.email=table2.email;
```

if you only want to set the empty emails:

```
update table1
inner join table2 on table1.linkID = table2.id
set table1.email=table2.email
where table1.email = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update table2 set email = (select email from table1 where table1.linkId = table2.id)
```

Comment: are you sure that TOP works in mysql ? and why you what update table2 ?